# how to replace 2 | by nothing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

if someone could give me the correct replace for :
`|TEST_1608224413246_Jean_Lol|`
replace both `|` with nothing

I have already tested `messagenew.replace("|", "");` but it only replace the first `|`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Answer (score 4):

### Using [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
// define let to store the test string
let s = '|TEST_1608224413246_Jean_Lol|'

// use string.replace to use regex to find and replace the | character
// | is a special character in regex so we must use \| to escape it
// using g to globally replace this means find all
// second parameter is what to replace it with empty string
s = s.replace(/\|/g, '')

// log the result as this is a demo
console.log(s)
```

### Using [string.replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
// define let to store the test string
let s = '|TEST_1608224413246_Jean_Lol|'

// use string.replaceAll to find and replace the | character
s = s.replaceAll('|', '')

// log the result as this is a demo
console.log(s)
```

### Note

This would replace any and all `|` not just 2, if specific number 2 is important here the regex could be updated to locate the beginning and end of string and replace them only from there.